# handle structure empty with uiwait in matlab gui at output function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I want to use uiwait according to this [example code](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_guis/making-multiple-guis-work-together.html#brav1u1) for sharing data between guis.
However if I call `uiwait(handles.figure1);` the handles structure is empty at `uitest_OutputFcn`.

```
function varargout = uitest(varargin)

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @uitest_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @uitest_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before uitest is made visible.
function uitest_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

% Choose default command line output for uitest
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes uitest wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% --> enable to generate error
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = uitest_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function menuClose_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to menuClose (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

uiresume(handles.figure1);

close(handles.figure1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure must not be deleted in the close function:

```
% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = uitest_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;

% The figure can be deleted now
delete(handles.figure1);

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function menuClose_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to menuClose (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

close(handles.figure1);

% --- Executes when user attempts to close figure1.
function figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: delete(hObject) closes the figure
if isequal(get(hObject, 'waitstatus'), 'waiting')
    % The GUI is still in UIWAIT, us UIRESUME
    uiresume(hObject);
else
    % The GUI is no longer waiting, just close it
    delete(hObject);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had a hard time finding an answer to this question. Using "close(handles.figure1);" in the button callback function solved it for me too.